# c++ extract number from a string and sum it up

Tags: c++

Hi guys i have this set of data in **.txt** that contain positive and negative number in between a string with **`":" as delimeter`**. How can i extract out the negative number and sum it up to display. I tried using substr but the position is not fixed.

**text file:**

```
tom12:Phone Bill:-45.90:12JAN14
tom12:Utility Bill:-133.50:17JAN15
tom12:Housing Bill:-200.78:01JAN15
tom12:Salary:2700.00:02FEB15
tom12:Miscellaneous:-30.52:20JAN15
tom12:Child Needs:-80.95:15JAN15
```

Sorry maybe my qn wasn't clear. I want to read every line and get the double in the string (-45.00, -133.50, -200.70, 2700.00, -30.522, -80.95) and sum up all negative into (-491.65) then use then salary minus off to the balance (2700 - 491.65 = 2208.35) Hope this is clear

Comment: What you had tried so far? Also you can get the third part of every line using getline and then you can convert it into integer and then sum up them.

Comment: Specifically what numbers are you trying to sum? Edit your post and put them in bold.

Comment: Someone answer my qn and is gone now. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hopefully help you.

```
std::ifstream file("your_file");
std::string   line;
int totalNegative = 0;
int totalPositive = 0;
while(std::getline(file, line))
{
   std::stringstream   linestream(line);
   std::string         data1;
   std::string         data2;
   int                 val3;
   std::string         data4;//If you want fourth string you can use.

   getline(linestream, data1, ':');//Getting tom12
   getline(linestream, data2, ':');//Getting Phone Bill
   // Read the integers using the operator >>
   linestream >>val3;

   if(val3 > 0)
      totalPositive += val3;
   else
      totalNegative += val3;
}
cout <<Difference is " << (totalPositive-totalNegative);
```

**std::ifstream** is an **`Input stream class to operate on files`**.

Objects of this class maintain a filebuf object as their internal stream buffer, which performs **`input/output operations on the file`** they are associated with

**std::stringstream** is a **`Stream class to operate on strings`**.

Objects of this class use a **`string buffer that contains a sequence of characters`**. You can split the string with delimiter with this std::stringstream

Comment: wah thanks i didn't know can use delimiter in getline. But i don't understand this line std::stringstream   linestream(line);

Comment: I updated the answer. Mark it answer and helpful if it help you.

Comment: so sorry my data is double not an int, when i change the val3 to double and compile they did not count in the decimal all. and when i try to print they only print data1 and data2. 
cout << data1 << data2 << data3 << data4 << endl;